# Checking a Checkbox (in header template) in Gridview and other Chekcboxes (in item templates) get checked as well jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I want when I check the checkbox in the header template, then other checkboxes in the Item Template should get checked as well Unfortunately this is not working as expected. I added script referencing a the jquery version 1.6.2 in the head tag of the HTML  then a function that which will be fired after the checked box is clicked. Also on the Checkbox in the Header Template, the onclick function has the jquery function which I wrote in the at the head tag. The Alert is working fine. I did this to help me test that Jquery is working. Notice no AutoPostBack attributes But the Toggling is not working.

```
//this script is in the head tag
function toggleSelectionUsingHeaderCheckBox(source) {
    $("#GridView1 input[name$='cbDelete']").each(function () {
        $(this).attr('checked', source.checked);
    });
    //alert('checked');
    //the alert above is working fine
}
```

the Gridview code from columns

```
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="cbDeleteHeader" runat="server" onclick="toggleSelectionUsingHeaderCheckBox(this);" />
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="cbDelete" runat="server" />
        </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Id">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblEmployeeId" runat="server"
        Text='<%# Bind("EmployeeId") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="StaffName" HeaderText="Name" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="AccessRole" HeaderText="Access Role" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="LockStatus" HeaderText="Status" />
</Columns>
```

Comment: Check out the link below whether it answers your question https://forums.asp.net/t/1592506.aspx?select+all+checkBox+in+Gridview+when+click+to+header+checkBox

Comment: You don't need that ASP code to troubleshoot this; you just need a simple HTML page.  Get it working that way first, then adapt your solution to ASP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to loop through all the rows in the gridview, get the checkbox for each row and mark it as checked as shown below.

```
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField>
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbDeleteHeader" runat="server" onclick="toggleSelectionUsingHeaderCheckBox(this);" />
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbDelete" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Id">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblEmployeeId" runat="server"
    Text='<%# Bind("EmployeeId") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:BoundField DataField="StaffName" HeaderText="Name" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="AccessRole" HeaderText="Access Role" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="LockStatus" HeaderText="Status" />
</Columns>
```

Then javascript

```
<script>
    function toggleSelectionUsingHeaderCheckBox(chkbx) {
        var GridView1 = document.getElementById("<%=GridView1.ClientID %>");
        for (i = 1; i < GridView1.rows.length; i++) {
            GridView1.rows[i].cells[0].getElementsByTagName("INPUT")[0].checked = chkbx.checked;
        }
    }
</script>
```

The checkbox in the gridview header calls the javascript function which does the looping and checking.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This finishes the job for me

```
var gridViewId = '#<%= GridView1.ClientID %>';
        function checkAll(selectAllCheckbox) {
            //get all checkboxes within item rows and select/deselect based on select all checked status
            //:checkbox is jquery selector to get all checkboxes
            $('td :checkbox', gridViewId).prop("checked", selectAllCheckbox.checked);
        }
        function unCheckSelectAll(selectCheckbox) {
            //if any item is unchecked, uncheck header checkbox as well
            if (!selectCheckbox.checked)
                $('th :checkbox', gridViewId).prop("checked", false);
        }
```

To count number of items checked, use this before performing an action on your button

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#<%=btnDelete.ClientID%>').click(function () {

                var gv = document.getElementById("<%= GridView1.ClientID %>");
                var inputList = gv.getElementsByTagName("input");
                var numChecked = 0;

                for (var i = 0; i < inputList.length; i++) {
                    if (inputList[i].type == "checkbox" && inputList[i].checked) {
                        numChecked = numChecked + 1;
                    }
                }
                if (numChecked == 0) {
                    alert('No rows selected');
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    return confirm(numChecked + ' row(s) will be locked or deleted');
                }
                });
            });
```

then the html markup

```
<Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="cbDeleteHeader" runat="server" onclick="checkAll(this);" />
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="cbDelete" onclick="unCheckSelectAll(this);" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Id">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblEmployeeId" runat="server"
                    Text='<%# Bind("EmployeeId") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="StaffName" HeaderText="Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="AccessRole" HeaderText="Access Role" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LockStatus" HeaderText="Status" />
    </Columns>
```